# Using Matplotlib Output Client-Side in Browser With Skulpt

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, codeskulptor, skulpt

I am writing a Python application to be run client-side within the browser. The Skulpt project looks great for this, and I am pretty excited to begin working with it.

The one issue I can foresee, however, is that I will need graphical output using Matplotlib. Does Skulpt support Matplotlib? If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: Hold tight we're getting there. https://github.com/waywaaard/skulpt here's a start of the implementation of parts of numpy and mathplot lib in skulpt. He's moving it to separate modules so you can load them into skulpt.